# Extract data from file

Tags: perl, csv, text, extract

I have data like

```
"scott
E -45  COLLEGE LANE
BENGALI MARKET
xyz  -785698."
"Tomm
D.No: 4318/3,Ansari Road, Dariya Gunj,
xbc - 289235."
```

I wrote one Perl program to extract names i.e;

```
open(my$Fh, '<', 'printable address.txt') or die "!S";
open(my$F, '>', 'names.csv') or die "!S";
while (my@line =<$Fh> ) {
    for(my$i =0;$i<=13655;$i++){
        if ($line[$i]=~/^"/) {
        print $F $line[$i];
        }

    }
}
```

It works fine and it extracts names exactly .Now my aim is to extract address that is like

```
BENGALI MARKET
xyz  -785698."
D.No: 4318/3,Ansari Road, Dariya Gunj,
xbc - 289235."
```

In CSV file. How to do this please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of flaws with your original problem.  Should address those before suggesting any enhancements:

1. Always have [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of every script.
2. Your `or die "!S"` statements are broken.  The error code is actually in [`$!`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Error-Variables).  However, you can skip the need to do that by just having [`use autodie;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html)
3. Give your filehandles more meaningful names.  `$Fh` and `$F` say nothing about what those are for.  At minimum label them as `$infh` and `$outfh`.
4. The `while (my @line = <$Fh>) {` is flawed as that can just be reduced to `my @line = <$Fh>;`.  Because you're going readline in a list context it will slurp the entire file, and the next loop it will exit.  Instead, assign it to a scalar, and you don't even need the next for loop.
5. If you wanted to slurp your entire file into `@line`, your use of `for(my$i =0;$i<=13655;$i++){` is also flawed.  You should iterate to the last index of `@line`, which is `$#line`.
6. `if ($line[$i]=~/^"/) {` is also flawed as you leave the quote character `"` at the beginning of your names that you're trying to match.  Instead add a capture group to pull the name.

With the suggested changes, the code reduces to:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $infh, '<', 'printable address.txt';
open my $outfh, '>', 'names.csv';

while (my $line = <$infh>) {
    if ($line =~ /^"(.*)/) {
        print $outfh "$1\n";
    }
}
```

Now if you also want to isolate the address, you can use a similar method as you did with the name.  I'm going to assume that you might want to build the whole address in  a variable so you can do something more complicated with it than throwing them blindly at a file.  However, mirroring the file setup for now:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $infh, '<', 'printable address.txt';
open my $namefh, '>', 'names.csv';
open my $addressfh, '>', 'address.dat';

my $address = '';

while (my $line = <$infh>) {
    if ($line =~ /^"(.*)/) {
        print $namefh "$1\n";

    } elsif ($line =~ /(.*)"$/) {
        $address .= $1;
        print $addressfh "$address\n";
        $address = '';

    } else {
        $address .= $line;
    }
}
```

Ultimately, no matter what you want to use your data for, your best solution is probably to output it to a real CSV file using [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text%3a%3aCSV).  That way it can be imported into a spreadsheet or some other system very easily, and you won't have to parse it again.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } ) 
    or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();

open my $infh, '<', 'printable address.txt';
open my $outfh, '>', 'address.csv';

my @data;

while (my $line = <$infh>) {
    # Name Field
    if ($line =~ /^"(.*)/) {
        @data = ($1, '');

    # End of Address        
    } elsif ($line =~ /(.*)"$/) {
        $data[1] .= $1;
        $csv->print($outfh, \@data);

    # Address lines     
    } else {
        $data[1] .= $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: showing some thing error. `Global symbol "@line" requires explicit package name at name.pl line 8.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at name.pl line 8.
Execution of name.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
`

Comment: @user3341177 Yes, missed removing the reference to the old array.  Fixed.

Comment: That link adds no information.  It's the same as you've posted in your question.

Comment: Hello expert your code showing some error `Global symbol "$outfh" requires explicit package name at name.pl line 15.
Global symbol "@line" requires explicit package name at name.pl line 15.
Global symbol "$i" requires explicit package name at name.pl line 15.
Execution of name.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
`

Comment: Made my final update that shows you how to use an actual CSV parser to write out data to a single file for easy importing into a spreadsheet or some other program.

Comment: your code producing `scott,"E -45  COLLEGE LANE
BENGALI MARKET
xyz  -785698."
Tomm,"D.No: 4318/3,Ansari Road, Dariya Gunj,
xbc - 289235."` this result. It also including name

Comment: Yes, my final code intentionally joined them.  Now load up a spreadsheet program and import the csv.  If you want them separate, you could use the 2nd bit of code, but you didn't actually talk about your desired output format or goal.

Comment: If you don't want the name in the csv file, you can put the following line before the `$csv->print` statement: `shift @data;`.

Comment: Great stuff. I'd fix another flaw: hardcoding input and output filenames into scripts.